# Getting the version of Mozilla on my device and comparing with the latest version. Python, Windows

Tags: python, windows, mozilla

I have a task compare the latest version of Mozilla with the version on current device.
I wrote the code to get numeric value of the latest version.
Here is this code:

```
import requests
def get_ver_from_url():
    r = requests.get('https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US',
                     allow_redirects=False)
    base_usl = r.headers['Location']
    delimiter = base_usl.split('/')[-4]
    print delimiter
    return delimiter      
get_ver_from_url()
```

And now I want to get numeric value of mine version of Mozilla to compare it.

How can I execute it in easiest way?

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, nor is it meant to provide personalized guides and tutorials. See: [ask], [help/on-topic], https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users.

Comment: Also, why are you using Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

[In this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Command_Line_Options#-v_or_-version),It show your that how to see the version of Firefox.

In cmd,input `firefox -v|more` can get the version of it(after you enter the folder which Firefox install).

But I failed to save the output to a variable.
[image]

(BTW,If you want to use `firefox -v|more` in any folder,you should add `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox` to your system PATH)

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, *jizhihaoSAMA*'s method does seem easier (using `subprocess.Popen`). Nevertheless, here is another method utilising `win32api`:

```py
import requests, win32api

def get_ver_from_url():
    r = requests.get('https://download.mozilla.org/?product=firefox-latest&os=win&lang=en-US',
                     allow_redirects=False)
    base_usl = r.headers['Location']
    delimiter = base_usl.split('/')[-4]
    print(delimiter)
    return float(delimiter) # You probably want this as a float or decimal, not a string

def get_installed_version():
    firefox_filepath = r"C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe"
    version_info = win32api.GetFileVersionInfo(firefox_filepath, "\\")
    product_version = version_info["ProductVersionMS"] # There is also ProductVersionLS to get the least significant 32 bits of the version number, but that seems unnecessary
    product_version = float(f"{product_version  >> 16}.{product_version & 0xFFFF}")
    return product_version

latest_version = get_ver_from_url()
installed_version = get_installed_version()

print("Installed version:", installed_version)
print("Latest version:", latest_version)
if latest_version > installed_version:
    print("Installed version is out of date!")
```

Output:

```
74.0
Installed version: 73.0
Latest version: 74.0
Installed version is out of date!
```

Comment: I changed the `print` statement to a function call. Change it back if you're using Python 2.x. Or better yet, update to 3.8.